# PHP printer_open is printing html tags

Tags: php

PHP `printer_open` is printing the html tags.
I use `printer_set_option` with raw and text but it prints the same thing.

below is my code:

```
            if($ph = printer_open()) 
            { 
               $content = $data; 
               printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
               printer_write($ph, $content); 
               printer_close($ph); 
            } 
            else "Couldn't connect...";
```

Comment: yes. I want the print layout to be same as the preview of receipt. I am doing a code to print a receipt using php.

Comment: When I use the .print() function of javascript the layout of the receipt is fine.

Answer (score 0):

With printer you can't render html with printer but instead you can use echo!

Example:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( "filename.php" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
?>
```